# How to map the two arrays with a duplicate value?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have two arrays.

```
$array1 = ['id_e' =>[91707, 91708]];
$array2 = ['id_s' => [18, 57]];
```

If I want to insert or delete into the database, I want to make one-to-many mappings on these two arrays. And the result I expect it to be a new array as shown below.

Final Array:

```
array (size=4)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'id_e' => int 91707
      'id_s' => int 18
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'id_e' => int 91707
      'id_s' => int 57
array (size=2)
  2 => 
    array (size=2)
      'id_e' => int 91708
      'id_s' => int 18
  3 => 
    array (size=2)
      'id_e' => int 91708
      'id_s' => int 57
```

I'm stuck after returning array1 and array2. I'm a beginner in php.

How do I do this?

Comment: You can not have an array like array2. If there are the same key, they will overwrite each other.

Comment: Your numbers are not correct, maby post the right array's?

Comment: @Lolka bolka : array2 is the name of my array. $array2

Comment: @Chillion : May i know at which line you find it's incorrect?

Comment: There shouldn't be the same key in `$array2` `id_s`.

Comment: @lolka bolka : Thank you! i have corrected. there is one key 'id_s' have two values.

Comment: What if the first array has more than one element?

Comment: Hang on, the values change in the final result? 91707 vs 91701 and 57 vs 59?!

Comment: ok i will edit my question

Comment: @Thank you Jack , it's 91707, another element 91708. In the second array it's 57

Comment: First array should be `['id_e' => [91707, 91708]]` too?

Comment: @u_mulder: yes it can be. It can be more than one. In this case, it may be many-to-many relationship.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is:

```
$res = array();
foreach ($array1['id_e'] as $ide)
    foreach ($array2['id_s'] as $ids)
        $res[] = array('id_e' => $ide, 'id_s' => $ids);
```

Comment: i have added this snippet in my code. And after i did a var_dump of $res like var_dump($res) .  it dispalys this Array
(
    [0] => 91705
)
Array
(
    [0] => 18
    [1] => 59
)
array (size=0)
  empty    . My output array is empty

Comment: There should be `id_e` and `id_s` keys in your array1 and array2. If there're none of them - change this code accordingly.